# Install BPEL Designer for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Recently i cannot install BPEL-Designer for Eclipse. No matter whether i try to do it with a CSV Repository or with the  Install-New-Software-Method, it does not work. I am using this URL: http://download.eclipse.org/bpel/site/. 
I use Eclipse Helios and get following error: Could not find http://download.eclipse.org/bpel/site/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to include the exact version of BPEL in the update site URL. 1.0.4 seems to be the latest so the update site URL is `http://download.eclipse.org/bpel/site/1.0.4`

Answer (score 6):

http://download.eclipse.org/bpel/site/1.0.5/ instead of http://download.eclipse.org/bpel/site/ works just fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this should help but recently I have been learning `BPEL` and its related technologies at a beginner level. I found an interesting `IDE` which is built on top of `netbeans` and provides orchestration capabilities and a similar drag and drop interface with a seperate one for service assembly. It is called [Open-ESB](http://open-esb.net). Also, to answer your question too this [video](https://youtu.be/4ftyrUE3Fj8) I found looking for installing `BPEL` designer provides quite recent versions of `JDK` and `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

here is the easiest way :

enter the `http://download.eclipse.org/bpel/site/1.0.5/` in the `work with rectangle` and `Add` it, then push the `Manage button` beside the `Add button`, you can see BPEL over there, after that choose it and push `Apply and close` button. `Eclipse BPEL Designer` will show up and then click next. you need to restart your system for applying changes.